# select one column + another with max date

Tags: mysql

I have this table. I need to select the one row where registration = 1 and select the one row where session = 1 and last created_at.

2 rows - registration and last session

I tried row_number over, but it not working in mysql. (?)

How to write join query?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MGHk.png)

Expected it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKlyH.png)

```
first row: registration = 1 - user_id = 1
second row: session = 1 - user_id = 1 - created_at = max(created_at) where user_id = 1
```

Comment: provide your expected output

Comment: 2 rows. One where registration = 1, one last session: table.session = 1 and table.created_at = max(created_at) where user_id = 1

Comment: MYSQL does not have window functions until version 8.What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Version is 5.6.42

Comment: Sample data an expected output as text on the question are much more useful than linked images.And you could simplify a lot.

Comment: You suppose just separate tables for register and session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a union with a correlated sub query to get the last session
for example

```
drop table if exists u,m,memos,um;

create table u (id int auto_increment primary key,uID  int, reg int, sess int,dt date);
insert into u (uid,reg,sess,dt) values
( 1 , 1,0,'2018-01-01') ,    
( 1 , 0,1,'2018-01-01'),    
( 1 , 0,1,'2018-02-01');   


select u.* from u where reg = 1
union
select u.* from u where sess = 1 and id = (select max(id) from u u1 where u1.uid = u.uid)
order by uid,id;

+----+------+------+------+------------+
| id | uID  | reg  | sess | dt         |
+----+------+------+------+------------+
|  1 |    1 |    1 |    0 | 2018-01-01 |
|  3 |    1 |    0 |    1 | 2018-02-01 |
+----+------+------+------+------------+
```